# "Better message him" or "Better (to) message him"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> Mary's watch displayed ten past seven p.m., twenty minutes after the
>   agreed meeting time. Better (to) message him.

Do I need the "to"? Why or why not?

(Note: It's a short story in third-person limited)

Comment: Are you trying to communicate "(She had) better message him" or "Better (to) message him than to..." what? Wait? Call? Go home?

Comment: Whether you omit the _to_ or include the _to_, it's still a sentence fragment. Based on the scant information given, I don't think it's really possible to say if it's "needed" or not. I understand the **meaning** of what you are trying to convey, but what kind of **tone** are you trying to convey? Who is saying (thinking) it's time to message this mysterious man? Mary? A narrator?

Comment: @J.R. It's a short story in third-person limited.

Comment: @alex - Why are you telling me this? Your question is short on [details](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please); you should be adding them to the question, not revealing them piecemeal in comments.

Comment: @J.R. Okay, added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the context, you do **not** need the "to."

When "better to" is used, it means that the suggestion is preferable to some worse alternative, either implied or explicitly stated.

> Brian was often upset when questioned about his lateness, but Mary really needed him to be on time. Better to message him.

In other words, it's better to message Brian asking him to hurry up, even though he might get offended, than wait without messaging him. Mary would rather risk upsetting Brian than risk waiting too long for their important meeting.

In your case, without the "to," it simply means the situation is making it apparent to Mary that she should message Brian.

> Mary's watch displayed ten past seven p.m., twenty minutes after the agreed meeting time. Better message him.

Similar usages are commonly seen: "We better get going if we're going to stay ahead of the weather." It could also be written "we *had* better..." I'm not sure if that's required for grammatical correctness, but I think either is acceptable in informal writing or speech.

> Mary's watch displayed ten past seven p.m., twenty minutes after the agreed meeting time. She decided she had better message him.